# Bootstrap 3 images alignment issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Good day, slight issue here, I cannot seem place all three of my images in the same row together, can anyone help solve the issue? the first is in one row, then the second and third overlap each other. I have already used bootstrap's 12 column grid but the other 2 just kept going down a row. Also, is there a bootstrap code where the image adjusts to the row? thank you for reading.

heres a js fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/wxofr2ae/5/
[image: page]

```
HTML:

    <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
          <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MWC</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </header>
              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                          <div class="box">
                              <h2>BEAUTY</h2>
                              <img src="img/link_beauty.jpg" class="bhw_link">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                          <div class="box">
                              <h2>HEALTH</h2>
                              <img src="img/link_health.jpg" class="bhw_link">
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                          <div class="box">
                              <h2>WELLNESS</h2>
                              <img src="img/link_wellness.jpg" class="bhw_link">
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>

      <div class="legend">
          <span class="key-container">.container</span>
          <span class="key-row">.row</span>
          <span class="key-col">.col-*</span>
          <span class="key-box">.box (custom)</span>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>


CSS:

@media only screen and (max-width : 767px) {
  .box {
    height: auto !important;
  }
}

.bhw_link {
  width:  300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a plunk or jsfiddle or something where we can see your code in action?

Comment: added a js fiddle link and had bootstrap connect to the internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay! I just solve your problem by doing just 3 steps:

Step 1: add the closing tag for the `<div class="box">` of the BEAUTY block.

```
<div class="box">
   <h2>BEAUTY</h2>
   <img src="img/link_beauty.jpg" class="bhw_link">
</div> <!-- you forgot this closing tag -->
```

Step 2: remove a redundant `</div>` tag of the `<div class="container">` block

Step 3: change the css class, make `width: 100%`, this step will solve the image overlap:

```
.bhw_link {
   width:  100%;
   height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed closing div `<div class="box">` and change css of

```
.bhw_link {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width : 767px) {
  .box {
    height: auto !important;
  }
}

.bhw_link {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MWC</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </header>
              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                          <div class="box">
                              <h2>BEAUTY</h2>
                              <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="bhw_link"></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                          <div class="box">
                              <h2>HEALTH</h2>
                              <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="bhw_link">
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                          <div class="box">
                              <h2>WELLNESS</h2>
                              <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="bhw_link">
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>

      <div class="legend">
          <span class="key-container">.container</span>
          <span class="key-row">.row</span>
          <span class="key-col">.col-*</span>
          <span class="key-box">.box (custom)</span>
      </div>
```

Comment: wow what a quick fix, ill check on closing tags better next time.

Answer (score 0):

It's just because you ommitted the closing tag

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="box">
      <h2>BEAUTY</h2>
      <img src="img/link_beauty.jpg" class="bhw_link">
   </div> <!-- you omitted this closing tag-->
</div>
```

Try class "img-responsive" for your image tag if you want to scale the image to the parent element or just set it to width 100% because the image is already inside the grid system of bootstrap